# Unable to CURL a remote file

Tags: curl

I have a piece of code that is designed to receive any URL and rip it down from the web.  So far it's been working fine, until someone gave it this URL:

http://www.aspensurgical.com/static/images/aspen_hill-rom_logo.png

If I hit it from my browser, it shows just fine.  But when I try to CURL it down, I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /static/images/aspen_hill-rom_logo.png
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>  Server at www.aspensurgical.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

The CURL code I'm using is:

```
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(' ', '%20', $url));
$fh = fopen($local_file, "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Is their server somehow realizing I'm not a normal browser and booting me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have useragent check to see who you are. Add normal browser's useragent and you should be fine.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
```

Here's working example in [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CEA1bg).

Comment: You, sir, deserve a great big cookie.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: can you explain useragent, what about chrome, safari, and other browser, why we need to add them?

Comment: @Naeem Every browser sends his own user agent string to identify itself. Common search engine bots show in user agent string which search engine they work for. That's why some websites dig into this string to see who requests the page.

Comment: Even with user-agent set, this is not working for me when I try to `curl 'https://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html/?fromCurr=USD&toCurr=EUR&fee=0&exchangedate=02/08/2018'`

Comment: Did not expect this to be the fix, thanks! If it helps anyone else: I was running into this error after upgrading a server from Debian Wheezy to Jessie, which included an Apache 2.2 to 2.4 upgrade, and a php 5.4 to 5.6 upgrade. In 2018 yes, I know, I know...

Answer (score 2):

Some servers, in order to block unnecessary traffic, allow any download only from a browser. So, to dupe such servers, curl has an additional option of --user-agent  , which does the trick!

I use curl from my windows7 PC, have installed gow.

Example

```
curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0" http://www.example.com/archives/abc.txt --output pqr.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem
fix

```
<form action="gc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="f">
<input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['f']['tmp_name'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['f']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['f']['type'], 
    $_FILES['f']['name']);
    $data = array("myfile" =>$cfile);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://your-url/accept.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 15);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if($response == true) {
        echo "File posted";
    } else { 
        echo "Error" . curl_error($ch);
    }
    }
    ?>
```

and accept.php

```
   <?php
     if(isset($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
     $path = "myfiles/" . $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $path);
     }

     ?>
```